# Select value where most values exist of SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a user table where each record has a label. I want to select the label which occurs most in the user table. For example:

1. Username   Red
2. Username   Red
3. Username   Blue
4. Username   Blue
5. Username   Blue

The result must be an array containing: Blue, Red, as the label blue occurs more in the table than red. How can I obtain this result?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't think the db schema should be posted, and the result needs to be stored in a php array.

Comment: *"Error: Unknown column 'label' in 'field list'"* - You see Gordon's answer using `select label` was based on what you wrote in your question: *"as the label blue occurs more in the table"*. Then the missing CI/PHP code makes it all that much harder for people to give you the right time of day.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, well that's also exactly my database table structure. I have labels (blue, red, etc.) and usernames.

Comment: I'm not sure if Gordon knows CI, but I know his SQL skills are impeccable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `limit`:

```
select label
from t
group by username
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

This value has a name in statistics.  It is called the "mode".

Comment: Error: Unknown column 'label' in 'field list'

Comment: @P.Yntema You said "each record has a label". What's the name of the column containing the label? Use that in the query.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `group by label`, since we want the count of users with the same label?

Comment: Accidentally mixed up label and username. @Barmar